# .env file for Laravel keeps updating on Plesk git

Tags: laravel, git, plesk

I have a git repo on Plesk which is set on automatic deploy. The master branch is set to automatically deploy to the main website directory. Then I created another branch called Develop where I gave been doing most of my development work.

However the problem is every time I push changes to the remote server, the .env on the server file always updates to my local version

I have already had .env included in my .gitignore and ran (locally) "git rm .env" and pushing the update to the remote repo on plesk.

This still hasn't done the update.

Does anyone have any ideas? It's making development cumbersome as every time I push to my develop branch, I am having to use ftp to overwrite my remote .env file

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend putting env files in git.

Comment: Is the problem that .env is still in your git repo even after you did `git rm .env`?